# Using zgrep and awk to retrieve specific digits from a file name that matches a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

Whats wrong in this for loop?

```
for file in `zgrep -l 'REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:              [1-9]'`
do
    gzcat $file | grep 'REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:' | awk '{print $4}'  > /home/users/xyz/sample.txt
done
```

What I am trying to do is:

In a directory there many files in compressed format (e.g abc.gz).

But I want the files containing the pattern 'REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:              [1-9]'.

Specifically I'm interested in the [1-9] part of the such file names, that's why I'm using `awk 'print{print $4}'`.

But the problem is I am not getting the desired output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any output for `gzcat abc.gz | grep 'REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:'` command

Comment: Yes. I also got hte output for the command
gzcat abc.gz | grep 'REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:'| awk '{print $4}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your loop like this:

```
for file in *.gz
do
    gzcat "$file" | awk '/REJECTED PACKS TOTALS:/{print $4}' >> /home/users/xyz/sample.txt
done
```